# Getting all the rows using ORM expressions inside entities

Tags: symfony

I cant find a good documentation about the "ORM expression" i see inside of my entities, so im a bit confuse.

I have this inside my *user* entity:

```
/**
* @var ArrayCollection $administered
*
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Done\PunctisBundle\Entity\Brand", inversedBy="admins")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_brand_administered")
**/
protected $administered;
```

This is working fine, but i need something more simple, i need the var *administrated* to get all the values of the *Brand* entity instead of joining the table user_brand_administrated like it does on the code bellow.  How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want all the value here ?

With a custom EntityRepository you can use a method to retrieve your object like you want.

For exemple.

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneWithRelation($id)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u, b')
            ->leftJoin('u.administered, b')
            ->where('u.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

And attach this repository with your user entity:

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass = "Path\To\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
// ...
}
```

Like this you can retrieve your user with all the brands.

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I just need all the rows inside the Brand table formatted as a symfony object of course